How to log IntersectionOverUnion with mlflow logger and lightning?
I use lightning IntersectionOverUnion with the class_metrics=True
This returns something like:
{'iou': tensor(0.0514, grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward0>),
 'iou/cl_0': tensor(nan, grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward0>),
 'iou/cl_1': tensor(0.0492, grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward0>),
 'iou/cl_2': tensor(0.4061, grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward0>)}

The problem is two fold:

I don't have my class names. How can I determine which class each label corresponds to?
I'm unable to log the metric because of the name of the key


Problem 1
I checked the IntersectionOverUnion implementation in Lightning, and here is how it's handled:
    def compute(self) -> dict:
        """Computes IoU based on inputs passed in to ``update`` previously."""
        score = torch.cat([mat[mat != self._invalid_val] for mat in self.iou_matrix], 0).mean()
        results: Dict[str, Tensor] = {f"{self._iou_type}": score}

        if self.class_metrics:
            gt_labels = dim_zero_cat(self.groundtruth_labels)
            classes = gt_labels.unique().tolist() if len(gt_labels) > 0 else []
            for cl in classes:
                masked_iou, observed = torch.zeros_like(score), torch.zeros_like(score)
                for mat, gt_lab in zip(self.iou_matrix, self.groundtruth_labels):
                    scores = mat[:, gt_lab == cl]
                    masked_iou += scores[scores != self._invalid_val].sum()
                    observed += scores[scores != self._invalid_val].numel()
                results.update({f"{self._iou_type}/cl_{cl}": masked_iou / observed})
        return results

Therefore, it tries to get the labels from the self.groundtruth_labels which is updated at that moment:
    def update(self, preds: List[Dict[str, Tensor]], target: List[Dict[str, Tensor]]) -> None:
        """Update state with predictions and targets."""
        _input_validator(preds, target, ignore_score=True)

        for p, t in zip(preds, target):
            det_boxes = self._get_safe_item_values(p["boxes"])
            gt_boxes = self._get_safe_item_values(t["boxes"])
            self.groundtruth_labels.append(t["labels"])

            iou_matrix = self._iou_update_fn(det_boxes, gt_boxes, self.iou_threshold, self._invalid_val)  # N x M
            if self.respect_labels:
                label_eq = p["labels"].unsqueeze(1) == t["labels"].unsqueeze(0)  # N x M
                iou_matrix[~label_eq] = self._invalid_val
            self.iou_matrix.append(iou_matrix)

Unfortunately, the labels are encoded into [1,2,3] and don't correspond anymore to the original classes. Thus, The information is lost. Where can I retrieve the original class information from? I'm unsure how to properly use this class, what would be the canonical way?

Problem 2
When I attempt to log my IoU in my module, I encounter the following:
My code:
# Training IoU computation
self.model.eval()
outputs = self.model(images)
self.iou.update(outputs, targets)
train_iou = self.iou.compute()
self.iou.reset()

self.log_dict(
   train_iou,
   on_step=False,
   on_epoch=True,
   logger=True,
)

the error:
Error Traceback:
---
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotADirectoryError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/file_store.py:1058, in FileStore.log_batch(self, run_id, metrics, params, tags)
   1057 for metric in metrics:
-> 1058     self._log_run_metric(run_info, metric)
   1059 for tag in tags:
   1060     # NB: If the tag run name value is set, update the run info to assure
   1061     # synchronization.

File ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/file_store.py:937, in FileStore._log_run_metric(self, run_info, metric)
    936 make_containing_dirs(metric_path)
--> 937 append_to(metric_path, f"{metric.timestamp} {metric.value} {metric.step}\n")

File ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mlflow/utils/file_utils.py:505, in append_to(filename, data)
    504 def append_to(filename, data):
--> 505     with open(filename, "a") as handle:
    506         handle.write(data)

NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: './mlruns/631769544733170278/78fb55d679a149a1ad098a032995ad17/metrics/iou/cl_0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MlflowException: [Errno 20] Not a directory: './mlruns/631769544733170278/78fb55d679a149a1ad098a032995ad17/metrics/iou/cl_0'
---

Because of the / in the name, mlflow is unable to store it into it's mlruns folder.

Question
How to properly handle this situation and log IoU using lightning framework in mlflow ?
